# pass computed property as method parameter?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

So I have a store with values:

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        selectedGradeId: null,
    },
    getters:{
        selectedGradeId: state => {
            return state.selectedGradeId
        },
    },
    mutations:{
        SET_SELECTED_GRADE_ID(state, gradeid){
            state.selectedGradeId = gradeid
        },
        CLEAR_SELECTED_GRADE_ID(state){
            state.selectedGradeId = null
        },       
    },
    actions:{
        loadStudentsForGrade (gradeId) {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    axios.get('/students/'+gradeId)
                        .then((response)=>{
                            ... do stuff
                            resolve(response)
                        }, response => {
                            reject(response)
                        })
                })
        },
    }
})
```

and inside my component i basically have a select that loads the student list for the particular grade:

```
<select id="grades" name="grades" v-model="selectedGradeId" @change="loadStudentsForGrade(selectedGradeId)"

methods: {
            loadStudentsForGrade(gradeId) {
                this.$store.dispatch('loadStudentsForGrade', {gradeId})
                    .then(response => {             
                }, error => {                   
                })
            },
        },
        computed: {
            selectedGradeId: {
                get: function () {
                    return this.$store.getters.selectedGradeId;
                },
                set: function (gradeId) {
                    this.$store.commit('SET_SELECTED_GRADE_ID', gradeId);
                }
            },          

        }
```

when the 'loadStudentsForGrade' method is called in my component, it takes 'selectedGradeId' as a parameter, which is a computed property.
Now the problem I have is that inside my store, the action 'loadStudentsForGrade' gets an object( i guess computed?) instead of just the gradeid

object i get is printed to console:
{dispatch: ƒ, commit: ƒ, getters: {…}, state: {…}, rootGetters: {…}, …}

Comment: If you're setting the `gradeId` into the store via the computed _setter_, why bother passing it in to the `loadStudentsForGrade` action at all? Just pull it from the state

Comment: yeah, good point i didn't even see that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of your action is the store, and the second the payload.
so you should do :

```
actions:{
    // here: loadStudentsForGrade (store, payload) {
    loadStudentsForGrade ({ commit }, { gradeId }) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                axios.get('/students/'+gradeId)
                    .then((response)=>{
                        //... do stuff
                        //... commit('', response);
                        resolve(response)
                    }, response => {
                        //... commit('', response);
                        reject(response)
                    })
            })
    },
}
```

Related page in the docs : 
https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html#dispatching-actions